changing the width of a div with setinterval
I have this code with css animation:


@keyframes progress-bar {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: progress-bar 6s ease-in infinite alternate forwards;
  animation: progress-bar 6s ease-in infinite alternate forwards;
}
<div class="box">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>



This is an example link to codesandbox: link
This allows me to fill in endlessly div.line in three seconds and then hide it's width back in three seconds.
I want to implement in Vanila JS the same functionality with using setInterval. I understand that I need to use setInterval, loop and get the width using the clientwidth. But all my attempts either immediately clear setInterval or doesn't work.
Please help me find the optimal solution, thank you.

You can also use  another alternative with css variable and javascript as follow. If you want to reach 100% from 0% in 3s you need to set the interval to 30ms.


const line = document.querySelector('.line')
const root = document.querySelector(':root')
let lineWidth = 0
let increment = true


function incrementWidth(){
    if(lineWidth<100 && increment){
        lineWidth+=1
        root.style.setProperty("--width", `${lineWidth}%`)
        if(lineWidth===100){ 
            increment=false
        }
    }
    if(lineWidth > 0 && !increment){
        lineWidth-=1
        root.style.setProperty("--width", `${lineWidth}%`)
        if(lineWidth===0){ increment=true}
    }
}

let interval_ID = setInterval(()=>{
    incrementWidth()
},30)
  
  :root{
    --width: 0%;
  }

  .box {
    position: relative;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: var(--width);
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
    <div class="box">
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>




Hi man! Amazing and easy - good job! I am still cant to understand - why u choose 30ms for step?

@yanballas, thanks and you are very welcome!  30ms it is the time necessary to achieve 1% step in your progressbar out of 100% so you will reach 100% in 100*30ms = 3000ms=3s as you wished. Enjoy coding!

Here is a JS version - we still need SOME CSS
I just SET the width and use a couple of ternaries to increment of decrement it


const line = document.querySelector('.line');
let width = 0;
let growing = true;
const intervalDuration = 30; 
const totalDuration = 6000; // total duration of the animation in milliseconds
const maxSteps = totalDuration / intervalDuration; // number of steps in the animation cycle
const increment = 100 / maxSteps; // calculate increment once
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  // Increment or decrement the width based on the growing state
  width += growing ? increment : -increment;

  // Switch direction if limits are reached
  growing = (growing && width >= 100) || (!growing && width <= 0) ? !growing : growing;

  line.style.width = `${width}%`; 
}, intervalDuration);
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
<div class="box">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>




Hi! Really good solution! U can explain me more about intervalDuration and maxSteps? Why u choice 30 and whats mean maxSteps? Thanks!

30 milliseconds is a good number to approximate 30fps.
I got the 6 seconds from your CSS animation.  totalDuration / intervalDuration gives how many steps we need to split the 100% length in. but thanks for pointing it out, I changed the code to use 100/maxSteps to give the increment/decrement
